# Why is it that I can no longer access some folders in my old time machine backups and how can I get access?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, time-machine, backup, permission

So I recently had IT reformat my Mac OS 10.6 laptop to put a 10.8 image on it. When I first got it back I could still access all folders in my old backups, including the Library folder under my old user account folder. Now when I go into it the system tells me that I don't have permission to access it.

I have tried sudo to get into it from terminal with no luck. I don't remember if this problem started after I enabled backups on my new install of OS X. But this is very irritating. Any ideas as to why this is? I can no longer access "/Users//Library" for example. I just get a red circle icon with a white dash in it.

I tried changing the owner with chown. I tried changing the permissions with chmod to 777. No luck so far.

Why is this happening and are there any solutions for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried repairing the disk permissions via Disk Utility?

If that doesn't work, try enabling the root account, logging in, and attempting to access the files.

> - Use the "System Administrator" account to access the files:
>
>   1. navigate to the folder "**/System/Library/CoreServices/**" and open "**Directory Utility.app**"
>   2. Click the padlock
>   3. in the "**Edit**" menu, choose "**Enable root user**"
>   4. from the Apple menu, choose "**Log out**"
>   5. **log in as "System Administrator"** (or "root") and you will have access to the files in "/Users/Abby"

Comment: I have not tried those things yet. Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: Well, unfortunately the "Repair Disk Permissions" option is greyed out. I will try the second option later when I have time for logging out and in.

Comment: Well I should have gone back and done something with this. But I switched jobs about 2 weeks after this. So I never ended up being able to complete this on that computer. I will just mark this as a good answer for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with the Terminal, try granting the Terminal "Full Disk Access" as described in the article ["Time Machine: inherit a backup from another computer"](https://acecilia.medium.com/mac-and-time-machine-inherit-a-backup-from-another-computer-dbad4d8aad79).

If you would rather use finder, try unchecking "Ignore ownership on this volume" as described in the article ["Accessing old files in OS X after a hard drive upgrade"](https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/accessing-old-files-in-os-x-after-a-hard-drive-upgrade/).

Time Machine Backups are awesome but so annoying when all you want to do is access hidden files from old user accounts.

I was stuck for days trying to use Finder to browse files from an old Time Machine Backup to an APFS Volume and the file I needed was in the hidden Library folder that has 700 permissions for a UID that I am no longer using. I was getting nowhere while looking for a way to uncheck "Ignore ownership on this volume" which wasn't an option because instead the **Info** > **Sharing & Permissions** only says "You have custom access". I also tried `chmod` but Terminal errors with:

```
cd: permission denied /Volumes/.timemachine/UUID/dated.backup/dated.backup/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/username/Library.
```

In my case, all I needed was the "Full Disk Access" tip for the Terminal and amazingly I am finally able to access the Library files but using a slightly different directory structure.

```
cd "/Volumes/Backups/dated.previous/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/username/Library"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Finder or Terminal to browse through TM backups.

Use the Time Machine interface, accessed through the TM menulet.